# Contar registros por mes en una tabla MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en MySQL y quisiera realizar la siguiente consulta:

Necesito saber cuántos registros tengo según la fecha. El campo `fecha` lo tengo en el siguiente formato `2016-07-12`. ¿Cómo puedo saber la cantidad de registros por mes para el año actual?

Por ejemplo:

**Tabla `usuario`**

1. `id`
2. `nombre`
3. `dni`
4. `fecha`

Tengo la consulta para contar, pero no sé cómo formular el `where` para lo mencionado anteriormente.

```
select count(*) as cantidad_registros from usuario where ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu campo `fecha` no incluye hora, entonces puedes usar `BETWEEN` sin problemas.

Pero por si acaso, te dejo otra opción que funciona bien sin importar si el campo `fecha` incluye una porción hora o no. Y además tiene la ventaja que no necesitar recordarte de cuantos días tiene el mes, o de tener que ajustar la cantidad de días según el año si el mes que te interesa es febrero.

```
select count(*)
  from usuario
 where fecha >= '2016-07-01'
   and fecha < '2016-08-01'
```

**Edición**

con las nuevas aclaraciones, puedes usar la consulta siguiente:

```
select MonthName(fecha), count(*)
  from usuario
 where year(fecha) = year(curdate())
 group by MonthName(fecha)
```

...o, aunque se ve un poco mas complicado, la siguiente consulta es más óptima si tienes un índice definido en la columna `fecha` y tienes muchos registros con años distintos. La optimización se debe a que no aplico la función `year` a la columna `fecha`, lo que permite el uso del índice, si lo tienes:

```
select MonthName(fecha), count(*)
  from usuario
 where fecha >= makedate(year(curdate()), 1)
   and fecha < makedate(year(curdate()) + 1, 1)
 group by MonthName(fecha)
```

Comment: lo probare, y si necesito obtener un campo mas y mostrar de que mes son eso registros en esta caso 'julio'

Comment: Solo para aclarar, ¿la consulta es solo para un mes en particular, o quieres mostrar varios registros con varios meses y sus cuentas respectivas? Tal vez la respuesta de Lcop sea lo que mas te conviene.

Comment: creo que me falto especificar eso, fue culpa mia. deseo mostrar la cantidad de  registro de todos los meses, del año actual

Comment: En efecto. Sería bueno editar tu pregunta para aclarar eso. Especifica claramente el resultado deseado.

Comment: de hecho, between si acepta la fecha con hora incluyendo el detalle de los segundos.

Comment: @Rene: Cierto. Pero tienes que asegurarte de incluir `23:59:59` al final. Se puede, y muchos lo hacen, pero no es mi preferencia personal.

Comment: lo siento e aclarado la pregunta, en efecto el resultado del codigo de @Lcop es lo que deseo, con la parte que me falto especificar que sea los meses del año actual.

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta con tus últimas aclaraciones.

Comment: @sstan gracias, pero los el nombre de los meses me devuelbe null

Comment: perdon ya lo e solucionado muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu ejemplo me ha funcionado pues básicamente necesito lo mismo, solo dos preguntas: 1, como convierto los meses a español (o en su caso ponerle un número para desde php cambiar el idioma) y el segundo, ¿como los ordeno por mes?, pues en mi caso aparecen desordenados... https://prnt.sc/nteo0w

Answer (score 3):

Solo indicalo de esta forma:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM usuario WHERE (fecha BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-07-31')
```

Devuelve el numero de resultados encontrados con una fecha entre el *1 de julio al 31 de julio*.

Si lo que quieres es  mostrar la cuenta de cada mes prueba lo siguiente:

```
SELECT MonthName(fecha) AS mes, count(*) AS numFilas FROM usuario GROUP BY mes
```

Comment: lo probare, y si necesito obtener un campo mas y mostrar de que mes son eso registros en esta caso 'julio'

Comment: ¿es pregunta? no entendi bien. Si quieres agregar otro capo en tu consulta solo enumeralo en una coma. SELECT count (*), id, campo2, campo3... etc.

Comment: @Criss he actualizado mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

La consulta debe quedar algo asi

```
select MonthName(fecha) as Month, count(*) as numRecords from usuario where MONTH(fecha) = 7 Group By Month
```

En el caso de julio, si se quiere para todos los meses se debe quitar el where