# Query mysql, conteo registros por fecha

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problemita.

Necesito generar un query de esta manera:

```
+-----------+------+-------+---+---+
| nombreSol | Enero|Febrero|...|Dic|
+-----------+------+-------+---+---+
| pedro     |  1   |   5   |...| 2 |
| juan      |  3   |   6   |...| 4 |
+-----------+------+-------+---+---+
```

La verdad soy nueva en el area e buscado como hacerlo y no se como.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda..

Comment: Hola, lo que quieres decir es obtener el total de registro por la fecha que seleccionaste?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el diseño de las tablas de tu BD?

Comment: ¿cuál es el formato de la fecha?

Comment: posible duplicado http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42560/23233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo del nombre de las columnas y tablas, deberia ser algo parecido a:

```
SELECT 
    nombre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) == 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Enero,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) == 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Febrero,
    // ----
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) == 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Noviembre,
    SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) == 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Diciembre
FROM tabla
GROUP BY nombre; // -- o id en caso de ser posible
```

Comment: Miiil gracias!!! Funciona perfecto!!! Sólo tengo una consulta más.. los datos que estoy obteniendo son sólo del 2017.. pero que pasaría si fuecen de un año anterior? se aplicaría un where?

Comment: @AnahíReyes Cambiando la `fecha` debería bastar

Answer (score 0):

Dado el esquema que pones  y teniendo en cuenta que la tabla donde obtienes los nombres esta relacionada con otra, yo lo realizaría con queries anidados:

```
 SELECT a.id_nombre, a.nombre, 
    (SELECT count(*) from tablaB b where b.id_nombre = a.id_nombre AND month(b.fecha) == 1   ) as Enero,
    (SELECT count(*) from tablaB b where b.id_nombre = a.id_nombre AND month(b.fecha) == 2   ) as Febrero,...

  FROM nombres a
```

Este seria mi muy humilde opinión, suerte!!.